# UILabel customisation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uilabel

I don't know how to specify this kind of uilabel customisation but I want to add lines to the right and left side of the label and middle part will have the text. . I know one way is to take three labels i.e. left side label, right side label and centre text label but this approach seems to be inappropriate so suggest me a standard approach to do this programatically.

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: You can use a `UILabel` that will be centered and add two `UIView` on either side with the appropriate constraints instead of two `UILabel`.

Comment: and if you want to have a single control that you can add, you could create a custom control that embeds a `UILabel` and two `UIView` as described by @Rikh, in another `UIView` so that you can provide a simplified implementation that just takes a display text